# How to make a div disappear on a mobile browser when it loses focus

Tags: html, ios, css

I have a test page at www.iwanczuk.com/temp/test/nim.htm which shows the problem I have.  When viewed on a phone browser (I'm using IOS) if you tap on the trigger image a div with a list in it appears. You can only make it go way by tapping on the photo of the kitten.  If you tap on the text below the photo the list will not hide.  I have tried to put an action to make the list disappear on the div wrapper which holds the kitten image and the text but with no result.  I have tried different forms of this action based on searches I have done but nothing I've tried works.  I am trying to do this using CSS only.

HTML and CSS are provided below and any help would be much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>annoying problem</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="nim.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="list_trigger">
        <img src="trig.jpg" width="300" height="30" />
        <div class="list">
            <p>line 1</p>
            <p>line 2</p>
            <p>line 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="photo">
            <img src="kitten.jpg" width="300" height="250" />
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <p>Phasellus aliquet lorem congue felis sodales convallis. Nullam in bibendum lectus, a scelerisque quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In molestie mauris quis suscipit congue. Nulla facilisi. Ut tempus elementum eleifend. Nullam in congue magna. Donec laoreet lorem dui, sed tincidunt arcu ullamcorper eget. Aliquam et massa et elit vestibulum sodales ac eget tellus. Morbi id fringilla neque, sed porta augue. Maecenas suscipit augue ultricies, fringilla velit a, luctus libero. Integer eleifend tempor varius. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce ex libero, scelerisque ut volutpat a, ultricies id mauris. Nunc egestas neque lorem, in scelerisque tortor varius sed.</p>
         </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

.list_trigger {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    border: #000 1px solid;
}

.list {
    position: absolute;
    background: #FCFEEF;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.95;
    z-index: 20;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: #F00 1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
}

.list_trigger:hover>.list {
    display: block;
}

.wrapper:hover>.list {
    display: none;
}

.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 5;
}

.text {
    width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: This is the form of some code I want to use for a menu. The menu goes away if you click on anything in it but I want the menu to go away without activating any links in it when the user clicks outside of the menu.  It works fine on a desktop browser but the menu div only hides when you touch an image but not when you touch on any text outside of the menu.

Comment: On further experimentation I have come to the conclusion that this is an IOS problem related to text.  I added some onfocus tags to the HTML and found that the onfocus tag added to the text directly in the p tag has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:focus` psuedoclass and a `tabindex` on the div.

Here is [a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/10bwcmq6/) - click on the blue div to see the focus take effect and off it to reverse the effect.

```
<div class='dissappear-on-blur' tabindex='1'></div>

.dissappear-on-blur {
    background-color: #77f;
}

.dissappear-on-blur:focus {
    background-color: #f77;
}
```

The code is pretty simple, I used colours to show the effect more clearly in the example. You can replace them with the desired css for shown and hidden, for example, opacity.

Tab index is important to make the element focusable. It has the benefit of making the element keyboard focusable, which is useful for accessibility (remember your media query for a small screen can easily be triggered by zooming a desktop browser).

Remember that hiding something with `display: none;` will completely remove it from the document making it unfocusable.

[This example](https://jsfiddle.net/10bwcmq6/4/) is more complex, including a container and another div within the container. It serves to show the same effect applies in more complex contexts, involving parents and siblings.

You would need to wrap the css in an appropriate media query also.

Comment: Doesn't appear to help my example on a phone browser.  I changed hover to focus, added tabindex tags but the problem remains.  Once the list appears it only disappears if you tap on the photo, not the text.  I need to make it go away when you tap anywhere but on it.  Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: The example works perfectly in a traditional browser, it's just on a mobile browser that it fails.